# import error when using react-icons

Tags: reactjs

I have tried installing react icons, in my application I ran the npm command:

```
sudo npm install react-icons --save
```

I didn't get any errors, apart from some optional dependencies, that where skipped

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Whenever I try to import some of the icons, I get an error

```
./src/components/SkiDaysCount.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib/md' in ' 
'/home/kristoffer/ReactApps/navbar/src/components'
```

here are my imports:

```
import {Terrain} from 'react-icons/lib/md'
import {SnowFlake} from 'react-icons/lib/ti'
import {Calender} from 'react-icons/lib/fa'
```

Why am I getting this error?

EDIT:

i have also tried using the old syntax for importing, with the same issue as such:

```
import Calender from 'react-icons/lib/fa/calender'
```

Comment: Have you tried `import { Calender } from 'react-icons/fa'`?

Comment: @Tholle, when I try this I get the error that the folder does not contain an import named calender

Comment: Alright. Does `import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa'` work as a test?

Comment: Check this section of documentation https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#migrate-from-version-2---3

Comment: @Tholle this works actually... very strange

Comment: only the FaBeer works...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use the v3 way of importing the icons, you should not have `lib` be a part of the import path.

The icons also have the icon library name as prefix for the export.

```
import { FaCalendar } from 'react-icons/fa'
```

Answer (score 20):

After looking through the icon directories react-icons/[fa,ti,md] and looking at the index.dt.ts file for the new names of the icons I came up with your answer.

```
import { MdTerrain } from "react-icons/md";
import { TiWeatherSnow } from "react-icons/ti";
import { FaCalendarAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
```

To use the icons in your component use the tags:

```
<FaCalendarAlt />
<TiWeatherSnow />
<MdTerrain />
```

For an explanation look at the Migration from version 2-> 3 on the react-icon page.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons

Answer (score 10):

Not all the `fa` icons are free. I was getting this error when I was trying to import the paid icon of pencil as below.

```
import { FaPencil } from 'react-icons/fa'
```

If you see [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=Pencil) for all the fa icons, you can see that the `pencil` needs the [pro license](https://fontawesome.com/icons/pencil?style=regular).

As I was not having a pro license, I was getting the error. But we can always use the free [versions of pencil](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=Pencil&m=free), and we just need to import it as below.

```
import { FaPencilAlt } from 'react-icons/fa'
<button><FaPencilAlt /></button>
```

You should also check the implementation of your version from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons?activeTab=versions).

Answer (score 4):

maybe you have to update the "react-icons" package.
command:

```sh
npm update react-icons
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed the 3.0.5 version of react-icons, Do try :

For Pencil(Edit):

```
import {FaPencilAlt} from 'react-icons/fa'
```

For Trash Can (Delete):

```
import {FaTrash} from 'react-icons/fa'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import {FaHiking, FaRightAlign,...} from 'react-icons/fa'
```

from the v3 of react icons library '/libname' is mandatory.

libname as 'fa'-> fontawesome, 'fi'->feathericons. for more info visit

https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by typo error.
say

```
import {Haiking) from 'react-icons/fa'
```

instead of

```
import {Hiking) from 'react-icons/fa'
```

Comment: dude there is no different between above two code.

Comment: @lodey yes there is. First one has a typo: "Haiking" is not a real word.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are in yarn mode and you need to use `yarn add` instead of `npm install` to install a package.

Answer (score 0):

import { **FaCalendar** } from '*react-icons/fa*';

import { **MdTerrain** } from "*react-icons/md*";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mine was such an easy fix after all. All I needed was the full import name of the icon, even if just one icon always put curly {} and that was it fixed!
How many times do I delete node modules, install @latest and then realise ist the curlies! :-)

```
import {GoMail} from "react-icons/go";
```